# ajax and php - my code is somehow duplicate the elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am new in ajax and i try to learn it.
i got this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          
            /**Add Ajax**/
            $("#add-car-form").submit(function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();//prevent form to be submitted as null
                var postData=$(this).serialize();//get all the data from the form
                var url=$(this).attr('action');//the url is the action attribute
                $.post(url, postData, function(php_table_data){//send back the data from the url
                    $("#car-result").html(php_table_data);
                });
            });
        });//End Document Ready
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        <div class="row">
        <h2>Search our Database</h2>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search our inventory">
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2 class="bg-success" id="result"></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <form method="post" id="add-car-form" action="add_cars.php" class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="car_name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add car">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div id="car-result">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and i got the add_car.php

```html
<?php
include "../db.php";
if(isset($_POST['car_name'])){
    $car_name=$_POST['car_name'];
    $query="INSERT INTO cars(cars) VALUES('{$car_name}')";
    $query_car_name=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$query_car_name){
        die("QUERY FAILED".mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    header("Location: index.html");
}
?>
```

now, when i click submit in the form the sql statemant is working but some how i got a dublicate form as a result

here is a picture before insert data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJlrP.png)

and here is a result after insterting data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL6aH.png)

Comment: `header("Location: index.html");` - Why are you performing a redirect in an AJAX call?  What are you expecting to happen?  Generally an AJAX call would just return any data the client-side code needs, usually as JSON or even just a string.

Comment: Your add_car.php script should return some data instead of redirect to page with form.

Answer (score -1):

In add_car.php
Change your code like this

```
<?php
    include "../db.php";
    if(isset($_POST['car_name'])){
        $car_name=$_POST['car_name'];
        $query="INSERT INTO cars(cars) VALUES('{$car_name}')";
        $query_car_name=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if(!$query_car_name){
            die("QUERY FAILED".mysqli_error($connection));
        }
        $table="<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Car Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
        $query="Select * From cars ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if($result){
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $table.="<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cars"]."</td></tr>";
              }
        }
       $table.="</tbody></table>";
    
       echo $table;
    
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.